# WebAPI CORS and static files

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a WebApi, it is CORS enabled and works nicely.

I want to add static files which are served up by the API to be supplementary to the actual WebAPI methods.

The static files are served up just fine if you go to them directly, however if I try and ajax them in on another domain I get CORS issues.

The actual file in question is a static .html file.

I really don't want to create a wrapper controller to serve up static files as it opens a bunch of security concerns if I do it dynamically.

I am currently doing CORS with a custom `DelegatingHandler` (not the WebAPI2 builtin way) but this handler is not getting called for static files.

**How can I intercept static file requests in WebAPI and apply the relevent CORS headers where applicable?**

Comment: What is the `content-type` of the file you're serving and how are you doing it?

Comment: Maybe web.config would work for you? http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html : `<customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that looks like it could work but we dont want to open it up to everyone, we have a dynamic list of allowed clients. Is there any way we could set this from code?

Comment: @Dalorzo the content type is text/html i suppose? its a static file so i think IIS defines it dynamically based on extension

Comment: As far as I know you can't really specify dynamic values for this attribute in web.config and you can't change static file responses with code unless you force all request to be handled by ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

Using Marcus solution, I got my net core server working with cors, also for static files, complete code of startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using NotariasWebsDominio.Configuracion;
using System.IO;

namespace NotariasWebs
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
#if DEBUG
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                  policy =>
                                  {
                                      policy.WithOrigins("*",
                                                          "http://localhost:8081");
                                  });
            });
#endif

            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            // global cors policy
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
            
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfiguracionDominio.RutaDatos))
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(ConfiguracionDominio.RutaDatos)) Directory.CreateDirectory(ConfiguracionDominio.RutaDatos);
                app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions() { FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(ConfiguracionDominio.RutaDatos), RequestPath = "/appdata",
                    StaticFileOptions = { OnPrepareResponse = AddCorsHeader }, });
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
        private static void AddCorsHeader(StaticFileResponseContext obj)
        {
            obj.Context.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using `IAppBuilder.UseFileServer(...)` with `FileServerOptions` to serve your static files, you can add the CORS headers there.

```
var options = new FileServerOptions
{  
  ...           
  StaticFileOptions =
  {
    OnPrepareResponse = AddCorsHeader
  },
  ...
};
```

And your handler can just be (for example):

```
private static void AddCorsHeader(StaticFileResponseContext obj)
{
  obj.OwinContext.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
}
```

It's pretty broad but works just fine for me.

Comment: What does `AddCorsHeader` represent here. I'm unable to appy your suggestion in my logic. Same is the case with others also. Hence, you didn't get any upvotes, and your answer was not even accepted. Can you please improve your answer?